# is there available windows helpform in vs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application in c# and I wonder if there is ready/avaliable help form. I use toolstripcontainer and it creates classical symbols for us also help button in it, so is there classical help form in vs including search property etc?
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create your own "Help" text; and you'll typically put it into a .chm file...

... but here's the API you'll probably call from your "Help" button:

[Help.ShowHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ee1k5y.aspx)

These links should help with ".Net help authoring" in general:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165623%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165613%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://www.innovasys.com/products/hs2011/overview.aspx
- http://helpware.net/mshelp2/vs8/vs8help.htm